# Passport.js: Having trouble redirecting after Twitter login

Tags: node.js, twitter, passport.js

I'm having trouble redirecting my users to a specified page on my website after logging in with Twitter and Passport.js.

Here's the relevant code:

```
let prefix = 'http://';
let callbackURL = 'localhost:3000'

// Initiate the strategy, from the Passport.js docs
passport.use(
  new Strategy(
    {
      consumerKey,
      consumerSecret,
      callbackURL: `${prefix}${callbackURL}/api/auth/twitter/callback`,
    },
    function (token: any, tokenSecret: any, profile: any, cb: any) {
      console.log('Thank you for logging in', profile.displayName)
    },
  ),
)

// Where my users get redirected from twitter
app.get(
  '/api/auth/twitter/callback',
  passport.authenticate('twitter', {
    successRedirect: '/api/testing',
    failureRedirect: '/login',
  }),
)

// Where the Twitter login process starts
app.use('/api/auth/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter'))
```

At the moment `/api/auth/twitter` is redirecting me to Twitter and allowing me to login. Afterwards I get sent to `/api/auth/twitter/callback` which even triggers the `Thank you for logging in` console.log.

Unfortunately after that I'm not being redirected to either `/` or `/login`.

My redirect chain stops at `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/twitter/callback` and displays:

```
Error: This feature is temporarily unavailable
    at Strategy.parseErrorResponse (/home/leonardo/serverless-prisma-vercel-boilerplate/node_modules/passport-twitter/lib/strategy.js:206:12)
    at Strategy.OAuthStrategy._createOAuthError (/home/leonardo/serverless-prisma-vercel-boilerplate/node_modules/passport-oauth1/lib/strategy.js:393:16)
    at /home/leonardo/serverless-prisma-vercel-boilerplate/node_modules/passport-oauth1/lib/strategy.js:154:43
    at /home/leonardo/serverless-prisma-vercel-boilerplate/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:465:22
    at passBackControl (/home/leonardo/serverless-prisma-vercel-boilerplate/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:397:13)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/leonardo/serverless-prisma-vercel-boilerplate/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth.js:409:9)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1221:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

Any idea what this could be about? Is there something wrong with the way my redirects are setup?

This seems what [these people are experiencing](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-twitter/issues/86) but it's not of much help solving the core issue.